# Only show users that having cars more than one

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

Dear all I have **users** table and **cars** table.

and I have following **join query**:

```
select 
 users.id as user_id,
 users.username,
 users.job,
 cars.id,
 cars.brand as car_brand

FROM users 
 LEFT JOIN cars on users.id = cars.user_id

GROUP BY users.username, users.id, cars.id;
```

**Here is the snapshot:**

[image]

How to query for users that having **cars more than one**?

I tried code below but it return empty data:

[image]

How to get users that having more than one cars? (username: Ismed)

Comment: Group by ... Having count(*) > 1. Don't include the car id in your grouping, as this would result in 1 item per group after all

Comment: Why does your `car_brand` column seem to have missing values?  Can you show us the expected output?

Comment: looks AVi's answer, it's work very well on my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
You can do in this was as well. 

    select 
     users.id as user_id,
     users.username,
     users.job,
     cars.id,
     cars.brand as car_brand

    FROM users 
     LEFT JOIN cars on users.id = cars.user_id
    where exists (select username, count(*) multiplecars        
    FROM users u
      JOIN cars c on u.id = c.user_id
where users.username = u.username 
     group by 
      u.username 
having count(*) > 1 )
```

If the users have more than one car (even if same brand then this will bring those records) if you only want users with more than one branded care you can do count(distinct)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT users.username
FROM users
WHERE users.id IN(
    select 
    users.id
    FROM users 
    JOIN cars on users.id = cars.user_id
    GROUP BY users.id
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
);
```

Filter users first who has more then one car then get corresponding details

Answer (score 1):

The simplest and probably most performance method is to use window functions:

```
select user_id, username, job, id, brand
from (select u.id as user_id, u.username, u.job,
             c.id, c.brand as car_brand,
             count(*) over (partition by u.id) as num_cars
      from users u join
           cars c
           on u.id = c.user_id
     ) uc
where num_cars > 1;
```

Note that I changed the `left join` to a `join`.  If you have two matches, you are requiring a match.  I also introduced table aliases so the query is easier to write and to read.